# Angular lowercase and replace spaces with dashes in json data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my data:

```
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "result": {
    "items": [
      {
        "Name": "date",
        "Fields": {
          "{3C3170EE-E6D5-4075-A864-8AB86D1E8E98}": {
            "Name": "Promo Content",
            "Value": "September 22, 2015"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "rate",
        "Fields": {
          "{3C3170EE-E6D5-4075-A864-8AB86D1E8E98}": {
            "Name": "Promo Content",
            "Value": "10%"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "description",
        "Fields": {
          "{3C3170EE-E6D5-4075-A864-8AB86D1E8E98}": {
            "Name": "Promo Content",
            "Value": "This rate is good as of the date listed above."
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And here is my HTML and JS:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">

<div ng-controller="CallWebApi">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in data">
            {{ item.Name }}: {{ item.Fields["{3C3170EE-E6D5-4075-A864-8AB86D1E8E98}"].Value }}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script>
angular.module('myApp',[]).controller('CallWebApi', function($scope, $http) {
    // Local version of the data
    $http.get('./test.js').

        success(function (data) {
            $scope.data = data.result.items;
            console.log('success ' + data)
        })
        .error(function(data) {
            console.log('failure ' + data)
        });
});
</script>
</body>
```

How would I write out the description with letters lower cased, and spaces replaced with dashes?

I'm expecting:

- date: September 22, 2015
- rate: 10%
- description: this-rate-is-good-as-of-the-date-listed-above.

Comment: Writing a custom filter would be the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

quertyking,

create a custom filter with

```
var str = text.replace(/\s+/g, '-');
return str.toLowerCase();
```

[this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sjmcpherso/5WnTA/) does it

Comment: Thank you. I have seen this example. I am so low tech that I don't know where to put the code :( I will show what I have tried.

Comment: Thank you. This is perfect. I appreciate the time!

Answer (score 0):

Use the JavaScript function `replace("space", "underscore")` and the `lowercase` filter to solve your problem.

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in data">
        {{ item.Name }}: {{ item.Fields["{3C3170EE-E6D5-4075-A864-8AB86D1E8E98}"].Value.replace(" ","_") | lowercase }}
    </li>
</ul>
```